# Fabric.js canvas scaled + mouse control issue

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I have tried to find a way to get mouse control to work with scaled Fabric.js canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrks/Ce3XF/1/

```
   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');            
   canvas.setWidth(1000);
   canvas.setHeight(1000);
   canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({fill: 'red', left: 250, top: 250, width: 250, height: 250}));

   var text = new fabric.Text('Text inside canvas', { left: 200, top: 50 });
   text.hasRotatingPoint = true;
   canvas.add(text);


   canvas.upperCanvasEl.style.width = '400px';
   canvas.upperCanvasEl.style.height = '400px';
   canvas.lowerCanvasEl.style.width = '400px';
   canvas.lowerCanvasEl.style.height = '400px';
```

I can't figure out how to do it. Any help?

Comment: Can you pls explain what you are trying to achieve a little more?

Comment: If canvas is scaled out but other functions works normally(mouse control with objects), I would use this with the plugin so that users can design print quality designs.This means that frontEnd will work with the scaled out canvas(400x400px) and backEnd can export original size canvas(1000x1000px)

Comment: See if this thread helps https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/u8d_rwuNffI

Comment: This won't help me. I would rather zoomed out canvas and then zoomed it in to original size so I won't loose any image quality.